# when I run my code the output alignment is not accurate ,

Tags: python

```
from math import *

import numpy

element = {"1111":"The way", "1110":"Tail of the Dragon","1101":"The Boy","1100": "The Lesser Fortune","1011":"The Girl","1010":"Loss","1001":"The Prison","1000":"Joy","0111":"Head of the Dragon","0110":"The Conjuction","0101":"Gain","0100":"Red","0011":"Greater Fortune","0010":"White","0001":"Sorrow","0000":"People"}

z_array =[ ]

asia=["Life","Riches","Brothers","Father","Sons","Health","Spouse","Death","Journeys","Kings", "Good Fortune","Prison","Witness 1","Witness 2","Judge","Reconciler"]
for b in range(16):

    first =str(input(""))
    z_array.append(first)
    
    
europe_country =["",z_array[10],z_array[9],z_array[8],z_array[7],z_array[3],z_array[2],z_array[1],z_array[0],z_array[12],z_array[11],z_array[5],z_array[4],z_array[13],z_array[6],
z_array[14],z_array[15],]

print("House"+"\t"+"\t"+"Name"+"\t"+"\t"+"Symbol")
for b in range(1,17):

     asia1 = str(asia[b-1])
     country = "street"
     if len(asia1)>=8:
         print(str(b)+"\t"+"\t"+str(asia[b-1])+"\t"+str(element[europe_country[b]]))
     else:
         print(str(b)+"\t"+"\t"+str(asia[b-1])+"\t"+"\t"+str(element[europe_country[b]]))
```

The output alignment is not accurate when I try to run the script, please help me fix this.

I have added my code above.

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide us the code and the output, if you wanna get help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more details, and a minimal reproducible example with code you wrote yet / expected output  about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help. See MRE here: [mre]

Comment: @zanny, Please give the code and the required output. So that i will be able to help.

Comment: My code is too long can i please get help on how to change it into a link

Comment: @zanny: Don't change it into a link! Instead, boil the too long code down to a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor changes to the above code, but those are not necessary. If I will not made those changes then also no issues. And I am passing the below input while running the code,

```
1111
1101
1010
1000
1010
1110
0001
0101
0011
0101
0000
1111
1110
0001
1010
0101
```

The below output I am getting which is of proper format I guess,

```
House           Name            Symbol
1               Life            People
2               Riches          Gain
3               Brothers        Greater Fortune
4               Father          Gain
5               Sons            Joy
6               Health          Loss
7               Spouse          The Boy
8               Death           The way
9               Journeys        Tail of the Dragon
10              Kings           The way
11              Good Fortune    Tail of the Dragon
12              Prison          Loss
13              Witness 1       Sorrow
14              Witness 2       Sorrow
15              Judge           Loss
16              Reconciler      Gain
```

If the above format is not acceptable, pass the above inputs and let me know your expected output. So that I can help you.